# Use excel row with specific value openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to find a row in an excel sheet that has a certain value and then work with the cells in that row.

So for example, I want to find the row that has a value of "Yes" in column A. I've tried to do this with the following code (hoping it would print the number of the row with "Yes" in it), but nothing gets printed when I try this code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\rtemp\\Names.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet5']
strValue="Yes"

for row in range(1, 5):
  for column in "A":
    cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
    value= str(ws[cell_name].value)
    if value==strValue:
        rownum=row
        print(rownum)
```

Please can someone help with what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Far too complicated. Are you looking for just a single cell? Or do you have multiple lookups?

Comment: I'm looking to use a single cell to identify the row. So the values in a row might be: Yes, Value1, Value2. I want to identify that row by finding the cell with "Yes" in it and then access Value1 and Value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for a single value this is best approach.

```
sentinel = u"Yes"

for row in ws:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == sentinel:
            print(cell.row) #
            break
```

If you are likely to be looking for several values then creating a dictionary of cell coordinates keyed by value is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my machine, no matter if "Yes" is after row 5 or not.

```
strValue="Yes"

for row in range(ws.max_row):
    for column in "A":
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row+1)
        value= str(ws[cell_name].value)
        if value==strValue:
            rownum = row
            print(rownum)
```